# Code to discover Bluetooth devices in Java doesn't display anything

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth

I'm adding a piece of code to display bluetooth devices in Java.

I included the part that enabled the blueooth permisions (this is working as expected).

However, this piece of code seems not working to display the blueooth devices in the same page:

I can't see any visible errors in logcat. Also, I didn't create any specific box in the layout to display anything but at least I should be able to see the devices in the logs.

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private void btn() {
     btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
       discover_devices();
       // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
       registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
       myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
     });
}

 private void discover_devices() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            }
        }
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                System.out.println("Discovered: " + deviceName);
                Log.d("PERMISSIONS", "Discovered: " + deviceName);
            }
        }
    };
```

Any advice about this piece of code?

Android studio seems to obligate to check about the permissions in the Bluetooth code but this par of code is only executed after enabling the Bluetooth permissions manually at the beginning of the program.

Comment: As far as I understand, you cannot even see the devices in the logs when searching with bluetooth, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I'm not very experienced in java and Bluetooth but as far as I know from the official documentation that's what I need to just display the name of the devices. First I must register a broadcastreceiver and later I can invoque the start discovery function.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code and the permission method a bit, tested it on my phone and was able to view the bluetooth devices in the logs.

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> enableBluetoothLauncher;

 private static final String[] PERMISSIONS_LOCATION = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED
    };

private void checkPermissions(){
        int permission2 = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);

        if (permission2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    PERMISSIONS_LOCATION,
                    1111 //YOUR REQUEST CODE
            );
        }
    }

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        enableBluetoothLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                result -> {
                    if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        // Bluetooth open call func again
                        discover_devices();
                    } else {
                        // The user refused to activate Bluetooth.
                    }
                }
        );

        button = findViewById(R.id.clickButton);

        //CLICK BUTTON TO START SCAN
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    discover_devices();
            }
        });

    }


    private void discover_devices() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            checkPermissions();
            return;
        }

        myBluetoothAdapter= BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "device doesn't support Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                enableBluetoothLauncher.launch(enableBtIntent);

            }
        }


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {

                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            }
        }
        myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
                // object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    checkPermissions();
                    return;
                }
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
                System.out.println("Discovered: " + deviceName);
            }
        }
    };
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <!--BLUETOOTH PERMISSION-->
    <!-- Request legacy Bluetooth permissions on older devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app looks for Bluetooth devices.
             If your app doesn't use Bluetooth scan results to derive physical
             location information, you can strongly assert that your app
             doesn't derive physical location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app makes the device discoverable to Bluetooth
      devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <!-- Needed only if your app communicates with already-paired Bluetooth
           devices. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <!--bibo01 : hardware option-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false"/>
```

**And the log I observed when I did the scan:**

[image: Logs]

Everything worked fine for me hope it works for you.

Comment: Let me analyze your code thank you. May you please let me know, just to learn, what was exactly my mistake in my original code?

Comment: @SemirAdam Your Manifest file may be missing. Also, when checking the user's permissions, if there is no permission, you return directly, I asked the user for permission instead. Also, if the user's bluetooth is off, I added a code that asks for permission to turn it on. All codes other than that are the same as yours. Maybe it worked because I completed the deficiencies in your Manifest file.  Try adding the manifest and other things I mentioned to your code. As I said, it worked for me, I hope it works for you too.